# Show that: $a·c \equiv b·c\ (\text{mod }m)$ with $a, b, c$ and $m$ integers with $m \ge 2$ does not imply $a \equiv b\ (\text{mod }m)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Show that $a·c\equiv b·c\ (\text{mod }m)$ with $a, b, c$ and $m$ integers with $m \ge 2$ does not imply $a \equiv b\ (\text{mod }m)$

I've seen many similar examples, but can't seem to find a step by step explanation or solution to any of them (like an actual proof).

Comment: $(a-b)\cdot c\equiv 0 \mod m\implies (a-b)=km$ or $c=qm $ for $k,q\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You aren't looking for a proof, you are looking for a counterexample.  A single counterexample is all it takes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$2\cdot2\equiv 2\cdot5(mod\ 2)$ but $2\not\equiv 5(mod\ 2)$

Comment: why downvote ??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counter example. $a=b+1$ , $c=m$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counterexample: $4*4=8*4(mod16)$ but $4\neq8(mod16)$. Here $4$ is a zero-divisor of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z}$. i.e, an element $a \neq 0$ such that there is an no zero element $b$ such that $ab=0$.